# C# ReadToEnd , and change text

Tags: c#

*Welcome. I have a problem with the code.The program must change the text in "test.txt" on: 123456789 . I do not know how to write:*

```
string start = @Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Test\test.txt";
if (File.Exist(start))
{
    try 
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(k4))
        {
            String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
            (start) CHANGE  TEXT TO : 123456789 // At this point I have a problem;
        }
    }
    catch 
    {
    }
}
else
{

}
```

Comment: What "text" are you trying to change? Are you just trying to replace the file's contents with `123456789`? Is there a specific "thing" you're trying to replace within the file? Do you want to write the modified string back to the same (or a different) file? etc. Please update with both: what you've tried *and* sample input/output.

Comment: @user2960101 ??? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `File.WriteAllText()`

Ex : `File.WriteAllText(start ,"123456789");`

Answer (score 0):

use `StreamWriter` to write data to file

```
using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(start, false))
{ 
    sr.WriteLine("123456789");
}
```

*EDIT*

```
public StreamWriter(
    string path,
    bool append
)
```

*path* - The complete file path to write to.

*append* - true to append data to the file; false to overwrite the file. If the specified file does not exist, this parameter has no effect, and the constructor creates a new file.